# Labelling of square sides

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to label a square with irrational numbers. 
Let us say I have a square of size 2 $\pi$ $\times$ 2 $\pi$. But thought of showing the axis like this:
[image]

But when I wrote my code it's font is very small and numbers are very close by

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);

    \draw[thick] (1-0.2,-0.5) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
    \draw[thick] (-0.5,1-0.3) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};

    \foreach \x in {0,1/2,1,3/2,2}
    \draw (\x ,0.05pt) -- (\x ,-0.05pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {0,1/2,1,3/2,2}
    \draw (0.05pt,\y ) -- (-0.05pt,\y ) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you just add an irrational scale, like `scale=pi`?

Comment: @marmot Ok, Actually how do we do that?

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=pi,font=\Huge]` instead of `\Huge\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @marmot It's scaling everything altogether. Is there a way to keep the numbers small?

Comment: It does not scale the numbers, but you can keep them small by dropping `font=\Huge`.

Comment: @marmot Unfortunately it's doing that. [Image here](https://imgur.com/a/VpUPemI)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85797/discussion-between-shamina-and-marmot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can scale the axes by `pi` simply by saying `scale=pi`. And unless you add `transform shape`, texts won't get scaled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=pi]

    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);

    \draw[thick] (1-0.2,-0.5) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
    \draw[thick] (-0.5,1-0.3) node[anchor=south east] {$y$};

    \foreach \x in {0,1/2,1,3/2,2}
    \draw (\x ,0.05pt) -- (\x ,-0.05pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {0,1/2,1,3/2,2}
    \draw (0.05pt,\y ) -- (-0.05pt,\y ) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0);
    \draw[red] (0,2)  -- (1,1) -- (2,2) (0,1)  -- (1,2);
    \draw[red,dashed] (1,2)  -- (2,1);
    \node[align=center] at (0.5,1) {Fish\\ don't like\\ this island};
    \node[align=center] at (1,1.5) {Fish\\ island\\ 1};
    \node[align=center] at (1.5,1) {Fish\\ island\\ 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to fill in color in the fish island 1 but the boundaries color also go affected. Is there a way to fill color or shade but don't change the color of boundaries, here they are of red and black color (it's imp to keep the color)?

Comment: @Shamina Yes, load `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and do the fill inside `\begin{scope}[on background layer] ... <your fills> \end{scope}`, or, in this case, just draw the boundaries after the fill.